# How create RAID 1 on working Slackware 14.2?

Tags: linux, mdadm, grub, initramfs, slackware

I use Slackware 14.2 (with kernel 4.4.14-smp)
on sda and I'm trying to create the RAID 1 with additional sdb. I'm using the VM VirtualBox.

First, I have cleaned the sdb:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=8M count=1000
```

and copied the sda's partitions to sdb:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

Next, I've changed the type of partitions to "Linux raid autodetect":

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   8390655   8388608   4G 82 Linux swap
/dev/sda2  *      8390656 113248255 104857600  50G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       113248256 209715199  96466944  46G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       113250304 144707583  31457280  15G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       144709632 176166911  31457280  15G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       176168960 209715199  33546240  16G 83 Linux
```

and

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048   8390655   8388608   4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2  *      8390656 113248255 104857600  50G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       113248256 209715199  96466944  46G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       113250304 144707583  31457280  15G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb6       144709632 176166911  31457280  15G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb7       176168960 209715199  33546240  16G fd Linux raid autodetect
```

For each partition (md1,md2,md5,md6,md7), I did next:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --metadata=0.90 --raid-disk=2 missing /dev/sdb1
```

and made filesystems on created arrays:

```
mkswap /dev/md1
mkreiserfs -fq /dev/md2
mkreiserfs -fq /dev/md5
mkreiserfs -fq /dev/md6
mkreiserfs -fq /dev/md7
```

saved the raid configuration:

```
mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Next, /etc/fstab and /etc/mtab were edited by replacing sdaX->mdX
and the initial ramdisk were prepared:

```
mkinitrd -c -k 4.4.14-smp -f reiserfs -r /dev/md2 -m reiserfs:dm-raid -u -o /boot/initrd_raid.gz
```

Configured the grub:

```
cp /etc/grub.d/40_custom /etc/grub.d/09_swraid1_setup
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Slackware-14.2 GNU/Linux' --class slackware-14.2 --class gnu-linux --class os {
    insmod mdraid09
    insmod mdraid1x
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod reiserfs
    set root='md2,msdos2'
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.14-smp ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-huge-smp-4.4.14-smp root=/dev/md2 ro
    echo    'Loading inital ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd_raid.gz
}
```

I have edited the /etc/default/grub by uncomment:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
```

Finally:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And data were copied from sda to sdb (`cp -dpRx / /mnt/md2` and etc.).

GRUB was installed:

```
grub-install /dev/sda/
grub-install /dev/sdb/
```

Output at loading:

```
Loading Linux 4.4.14-smp ...
error: disk 'md0,msdos2' not found.
Loading inital ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

**The question is: which modules should I add to initrd and how should I config the grub?**

**UPD:**
/etc/grub.d/09_swraid1_setup was edited:

```
...
set root='md/md2'
...
initrd  /boot/initrd.gz
```

/etc/mkinitrd.conf was added to create initrd image:

```
# mkinitrd.conf.sample
# See "man mkinitrd.conf" for details on the syntax of this file
#
#SOURCE_TREE="/boot/initrd-tree"
#CLEAR_TREE="0"
OUTPUT_IMAGE="/boot/initrd.gz"
KERNEL_VERSION="$(uname -r)"
#KEYMAP="us"
MODULE_LIST="reiserfs"
#LUKSDEV="/dev/sda2"
#LUKSKEY="LABEL=TRAVELSTICK:/keys/alienbob.luks"
ROOTDEV="/dev/md2"
ROOTFS="reiserfs"
RESUMEDEV="/dev/md1"
RAID="1"
#LVM="0"
UDEV="1"
#MODCONF="0"
WAIT="5"
```

and initrd image was created with:

```
mkinitrd -F
```

after updating grub (`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `grub-install /dev/sda`, `grub-install /dev/sdb`) , system was rebooted sucessfully.
 After that, sda's **partitions type was changed to Linux raid autodetect** and partitions were added to array:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sda1
mdadm --add /dev/md2 /dev/sda2
mdadm --add /dev/md5 /dev/sda5
mdadm --add /dev/md6 /dev/sda6
mdadm --add /dev/md7 /dev/sda7
```

Now, the system booting with two disk is succesfull,but when I remove one of disks and try to boot, I get that:

```
/boot/initrd.gz: Loading kernel modules from initrd image:
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.14-smp/kernel/fs/reiserfs/reiserfs.ko
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'reiserfs': Device or resource busy
Trying to resume from /dev/md1
[    12.529675] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
[    12.552222] REISERFS warning (device md2): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev md2, block 2, size 4096)
[    12.557432] REISERFS warning (device md2): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev md2, block 16, size 4096)
mount: mounting /dev/md2 on /mnt failed: Invalid argument
ERROR: No /sbin/init found on rootdev (or not mounted). Trouble ahead.
```

**Now, question is: how to boot the system without one of disks?**